# ValueError: The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I uploaded image from admin panel and it get stored in media/img.I want to display posted image in my index.html but i get this ValueError: The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it.I think I am making mistake in url or view ..I am new to django.

```py
# app urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

```py
# project urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("blog.urls"), name="blog-urls"),
    path("summernote/", include("django_summernote.urls")),
]
```

```py
# views.py

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 3
```

```py
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts"
    )
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<img src={{ post.cover.url }} alt="{{ post.title }}" width="160px" height="220px">
```

Comment: Does `post.cover.image.url` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List view output is a queryset, means a list of instances, so you have to loop through it.

```
{% for post in object_list %}{% if post.cover %}
<img src={{ post.cover.url }} alt="{{ post.title }}" width="160px" height="220px">{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

also change the include url to

```
path("", include("blog.urls"))
```

without name, if you want you can add a namespace